Как сделать механику наград в Unity
Стал пробовать изучать юнити , сделал по гайду скрипт .С методом , который при подсчете  очков  , должен через for  определять давать  медальку определенную или нет .
Проблема в том , что медаль либо не присваивается , либо все время  присваивается одна и таже.Подозреваю ,что делаю что то не так в цикле  ,но не могу понять что именно не так . При таком вариате  i всегда  равна 0.
    {
        int score = ScoreManager.Instance.score;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
       
        int bestScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("bestScore");
        
        if (bestScore < score) 
        {
            bestScore = score;   
        }
        bestScoreText.text = bestScore.ToString();
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("bestScore", bestScore);
        Debug.Log(scoreText.text);
        for (int i = 0; i < medals.Length; i++) 
        {
            if (medals[i].ScoreNeed <= score) 
            {
                if (i > 0) 
                {
                    medalsDysplay.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    medalsDysplay.sprite = medals[i].MedalSprite;
                }
                else 
                {
                    break; 
                }
            }
        } 


Были строку  if (i > 0)  , удалил его , оставив просто  if (medals[i].ScoreNeed <= score) и все получилось
